# Elegant Python code for list decomposition

Tags: python, algorithm

I tried to write code to solve the list decomposition with All possibilities.
The code I wrote was a mess. I need an elegant solution to solve the problem, because I want to improve my coding style.

I tried to write an initial version as follows, But the memory requirements are too large and the execution speed is too slow.

```
import itertools

powerset = lambda iterable: itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        itertools.combinations(list(iterable), r)
        for r in range(1, len(list(iterable)) + 1))
flatten = lambda list2d: [item for sublist in list2d for item in sublist]

x = list("abcd") 
xxx = [val for val in powerset([val1 for val1 in powerset(x)] )] 
xxxx = [val for val in xxx if x == list(sorted(flatten(val)))]

xxxx is :
[(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),),
 (('a',), ('b', 'c', 'd')),
 (('b',), ('a', 'c', 'd')),
 (('c',), ('a', 'b', 'd')),
 (('d',), ('a', 'b', 'c')),
 (('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')),
 (('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')),
 (('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c')),
 (('a',), ('b',), ('c', 'd')),
 (('a',), ('c',), ('b', 'd')),
 (('a',), ('d',), ('b', 'c')),
 (('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'd')),
 (('b',), ('d',), ('a', 'c')),
 (('c',), ('d',), ('a', 'b')),
 (('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',))]
```

version 2:

```
import itertools

powerset = lambda iterable: itertools.chain.from_iterable(
        itertools.combinations(list(iterable), r)
        for r in range(1, len(list(iterable)) + 1))
flatten = lambda list2d: [item for sublist in list2d for item in sublist]

def makelist(list_1D):
    for val in powerset(list(powerset(list_1D))) :
        if list_1D == list(sorted(flatten(val))) :
            yield val
        if val == tuple(itertools.combinations(list_1D, 1)) :
            break
            
for d in makelist(list("abcd")) :
    print(d)

output:
(('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'),)
(('a',), ('b', 'c', 'd'))
(('b',), ('a', 'c', 'd'))
(('c',), ('a', 'b', 'd'))
(('d',), ('a', 'b', 'c'))
(('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'))
(('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd'))
(('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c'))
(('a',), ('b',), ('c', 'd'))
(('a',), ('c',), ('b', 'd'))
(('a',), ('d',), ('b', 'c'))
(('b',), ('c',), ('a', 'd'))
(('b',), ('d',), ('a', 'c'))
(('c',), ('d',), ('a', 'b'))
(('a',), ('b',), ('c',), ('d',))
```

version 3 from  [Time Complexity of finding all partitions of a set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845727)

```
def partition(collection):
    global counter
    if len(collection) == 1:
        yield [collection]
        return
    first = collection[0]
    for smaller in partition(collection[1:]):
        for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
            yield smaller[:n] + [[first] + subset] + smaller[n + 1:]
        yield [[first]] + smaller
```

Comment: So, you want to create a power set? Please confirm.

Comment: "Memory is too large" - dont make it a list then, use the generator as is. If you create a generator with million entries it takes memory to fully create it as list.

Comment: No, I want to create "Exhaustive list of possible partitions" .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65845727/time-complexity-of-finding-all-partitions-of-a-set includes elegant code to solve the problem that I think you're trying to solve.

Comment: I like #65845727, Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Questions about improving existing code are better suited to [codereview.se], but check out [their How to Ask page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/asking) first.

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid memory issues, we need to maximize the use of generators/iterators and never create a list of combinations.

Here is a way to do it by breaking down the problem in layers.

First, a generator to obtain partition sizes for a given number of elements.  This will then be used to fill combinations of elements corresponding to each size except for the single element parts.  The single element parts are done last in order to avoid duplicates.  By doing them last, we always have exactly the right number of unused elements for the single element parts.

**Partition generation**

```
# Generator for all partition sizes forming N
def partSize(N):
    if N<2: yield [1]*N;return
    for s in range(1,N+1):
        yield from ([s]+rest for rest in partSize(N-s))  

print(*partSize(3)) 
# [1, 1, 1] [1, 2] [2, 1] [3]    

print(*partSize(4))
# [1, 1, 1, 1] [1, 1, 2] [1, 2, 1] [1, 3] [2, 1, 1] [2, 2] [3, 1] [4]
```

**Partition filling**

```
# A generator that fills partitions 
# with combinations of indexes contained in A  
      
from itertools import combinations
def fillCombo(A,parts,R=None):
    if R is None: R = [tuple()]*len(parts)
    size = max(parts)  # fill largest partitions first
    if size < 2:       # when only single element partitions are left
        iA = iter(A)   # fill them with the remaining indexes
        yield [r if p!=1 else (next(iA),) for r,p in zip(R,parts)]
        return
    i,parts[i]= parts.index(size),0    # index of largest partition
    for combo in combinations(A,size): # all combinations of that size
        R[i] = combo                   # fill part and recurse
        yield from fillCombo(A.difference(combo),[*parts],[*R])
```

**Mapping partition to indexed values**

```
# for each partition pattern, fill with combinations
# using set of indexes in fillCombo so that repeated values
# are processed as distinct

def partCombo(A):
    for parts in partSize(len(A)):
        for iParts in fillCombo({*range(len(A))},parts):   # combine indexes
            yield [tuple(A[i] for i in t) for t in iParts] # get actual values
```

**output:**

```
for pp in partCombo("abc"): print(pp)

[('a',), ('b',), ('c',)]
[('c',), ('a', 'b')]
[('b',), ('a', 'c')]
[('a',), ('b', 'c')]
[('a', 'b'), ('c',)]
[('a', 'c'), ('b',)]
[('b', 'c'), ('a',)]
[('a', 'b', 'c')]
```

This uses very little memory but still has exponential progression in time.  For example:

```
sum(1 for _ in partCombo("abcdefghi")) # 768,500 combinations
```

takes 3.8 seconds on my laptop

Adding just one more letter, increases the execution time to 43 seconds for the 8,070,046 combinations.