# Time Complexity of finding all partitions of a set

Tags: python, algorithm, set, time-complexity, big-o

We know that this problem is np-complete, hence, no polynomial algorithm can be found for it. Also, we know that number of all partitions of a set is equal to the bell's number. I see there are few algorithms to generate all partitions of a set but couldn't find what is the time complexity to solve this problem.

For example, this python code generates all partitions of a set recursively. What is the time complexity of this algorithm? Could this problem be solved with better time complexity?

```
def partition(collection):
    global counter
    if len(collection) == 1:
        yield [collection]
        return
    first = collection[0]
    for smaller in partition(collection[1:]):
        for n, subset in enumerate(smaller):
            yield smaller[:n] + [[first] + subset] + smaller[n + 1:]
        yield [[first]] + smaller
```

Comment: A number of details & implementations are here: https://oeis.org/A000110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, note that this problem is not **NP**-complete. **NP** is a class of decision problems, which this problem is not. Often the distinction is useless semantics, but in this case there is no clear roughly equivalent decision problem. Furthermore, for a problem to be in **NP** the answer has to be verifiable in polynomial time, and to be **NP**-hard an O(1) oracle for the problem must allow other problems in **NP** to be solved in polynomial time. Neither of these is the case.

That having been said, you rightly say that the number of partitions of a set of size `n` is equal to the n'th Bell number. Now, because your code requires no search for partitions, it gives a partition "every step", and thus runs in time proportional to the Bell number. Technically there is also a polynomial term as larger partitions take longer to generate, but this term will be dominated.

What, then, is the big-o for the Bell numbers? This question turns out to be somewhat difficult to answer. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number#Growth_rate) mentions some upper bounds for Bell numbers, one of them found in 2010 ((0.792n / ln(n+1))^n), but there does not appear to be a tight bound proven.