# All possible summations within a list

Tags: python, list, combinations

I have a list of elements of a custom class Fun. What I want is to generate all possible summations of this list.
For example, if I have the list [Fun1, Fun2, Fun3], I want to generate the list:

```
[[Fun1 + Fun2, Fun3], [Fun1 + Fun3, Fun2], [Fun2 + Fun3, Fun1], [Fun1, Fun2, Fun3], [Fun1 + Fun2 + Fun3]]
```

This should generate for longer lists but I know that all elements of my list are of the same type, a custom class named Fun. And it is possible to sum elements of the class Fun, I already implemented the way they are supposed to be summed.

I have tried several ways to generate this list of possible summations, mainly using variations of itertools.combinations and itertools.product but without success. I have also tried list comprehension (things like `[[x + y for x in my_list if x != y] for y in my_list]`) without success. Usually, I get bugs like "type Fun is not iterable" or my output is only one element (the original one).

Comment: The expected output seems inconsistent. What about `[[Fun1 + Fun2, Fun3], [Fun1 + Fun3, Fun2], [Fun2 + Fun3, Fun1], [Fun1 + Fun2 + Fun3, 0]]`?

Comment: See also: `itertools.permutations` and `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: This answer should apply to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65854062/5237560

Comment: I don't need all my sublists to be of the same size, all I need is for my Fun_i to be all represented once in each sublist.

Answer (score 1):

It's very easy if you install the [`more-itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/) package.

So, first of all, install it:

```
>>> pip install more-itertools
```

Now you can do what you asked very easily. Since I don't have your definition of class `Fun`, let me do an example with ints. Please keep in mind that your class must support the summation of elements. That part is up to you to define.

```
from more_itertools import set_partitions

lst = [1, 2, 3]

partitions = [
    part
    for k in range(1, len(lst) + 1)
    for part in set_partitions(lst, k)
]

partition_sums = [
    [sum(p) for p in part]
    for k in range(1, len(lst) + 1)
    for part in set_partitions(lst, k)
]
```

```
>>> partitions
[[[1, 2, 3]], [[1], [2, 3]], [[1, 2], [3]], [[2], [1, 3]], [[1], [2], [3]]]
>>> partition_sums
[[6], [1, 5], [3, 3], [2, 4], [1, 2, 3]]
```

If you don't want to install that package, other ways to compute set partitions in python can be found here: [Set partitions in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368375/set-partitions-in-python)